# Passing output within the kernel in OpenCL

Tags: kernel, opencl

First can i initialize an array inside kernel like **"float output[3] = {0}"**

Second,I want to use the results that i get from part of kernel and use it in next part( in the same kernel).I wrote given kernel just for example, so i want to use values of **output[id]** and **output1[id]** in the next part to get **output2[id]** and **output3[id]** but it gives me **"PROGRAM FAILED TO BUILD"**

Suppose InputA[3]={1, 2, 3}

InputB[3]={1, 2, 3}

InputC[3]={1, 2, 3}

```
const char *ProgramSource =
"__kernel void add(__global float *inputA, __global float *inputB, __global 
float *inputC, __global float *output2, __global float *output3)\n"\
"{\n"\
"  size_t id = get_global_id(0);\n"\
"float a = 0.0f;\n"\
"float b = 0.0f;\n"\
"float output[3] = {0};\n"\
"float output1 [3] = {0};\n"\
"a = inputB[id] + inputC[id];\n"\
"b = inputA[id] + inputC[id];\n"\
"  output[id] = a;\n"\
"  output1[id] = b;\n"\
"float c = 0.0f;\n"\
"float d = 0.0f;\n"\
"c = inputB[id] + output[id]);\n"\
"d = inputA[id] + output1[id];\n"\
"  output2[id] = c;\n"\
"  output3[id] = d;\n"\
"}\n";
```

Comment: You have already received a correct answer to your question, but I felt I should point out that the way you're using the `output`/`output1` arrays doesn't make any sense in OpenCL: `float output[3]` declared like that in a kernel function defaults to `__private` address space. This means each work item gets its own private version of that array and cannot see other work items' arrays. You're only ever using index `id`, so at least this is only a waste of resources. Additionally, you don't need to put a \ at the end of each line - string literals are automatically concatenated.

Comment: Could you kindly explain a bit more that if i want to initialize an array inside a kernel then how should i do it. Thanks

Comment: If you need a (private) array, that is indeed how you do it, but you're only using `output[id]`. So if `id = 0`, `output[1]` and `output[2]` are unused (but consuming precious register space), if `id = 1`, `output[0]` and `output[2]` are unused, etc. In other words, there's no need for an array. In fact, `output[id]` has the same value as `a`, so you can just rewrite `c = inputB[id] + output[id];` as `c = inputB[id] + a`. Note that `a` and `b` are also `__private` variables, so each work-item has its own separate version of it, with potentially different values.

Comment: Nice thanks for explaining

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra parenthesis on this line:

```
"c = inputB[id] + output[id]);\n"\
```

You can call `clGetProgramBuildInfo` with `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG` to get a human-readable error message if your OpenCL program failed to compile.